# Check running PHP process in Windows server

Tags: php

I have been looking (searching Google) for a PHP script that will check if a particular PHP process/function is running however unable to find one that works in Windows non batch script.

I basically need to ensure the running of some processes don't overlap whether the script is executed from a webpage or from Windows schedule. Some processes should only be happening once.

I have tried pretty much everything here http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php but they don't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: log its start and end, other process can check if it its running based on the log

Comment: Posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129439/how-to-find-out-a-specific-process-is-still-running-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656350/php-check-process-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a "lock" file on script start.
2. Delete it once the script finishes.
3. Don't allow the script to start if it finds the lock file.

If you have multiple different scripts, just name the lock files differently.

Comment: Thanks. So will something like this work individually for each user as well? So say a user has 10 browser windows open with the same page and I only want a script to run once for each user, say get user messages for example. Would I just name the lock file based on user session (or something like that).

Comment: Sure, or store it in their session, as that takes care of the file for you.

Comment: Great. Thanks and will implement this.